# Drupal display suite template in module

Tags: templates, drupal, drupal-themes

I am using this function to register a tpl file in a module.

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_theme().
 */
function frontpage_carousel_theme($existing) {
    return array(
        'ds_1col' => array(
            'arguments' => array(),
            'template' => 'ds-1col--node-carousel-carousel',
            'original hook' => 'ds_1col__node',
            'path' => drupal_get_path('module', 'frontpage_carousel') . '/templates',
            'type' => 'module',
            'preprocess functions' => array('template_preprocess', 'template_preprocess'),
        ),
    );
}
```

this works fine, but is used for every node. I would like to apply it only to ds-1col--node-carousel-carousel.tpl.php, but

```
return array(
            'ds_1col__node_carousel_carousel' => array(
```

does not work. Does anyone have an idea ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to rewrite specific node-type template you should use `node--nodetype.tpl.php` file in your theme's folder.

Comment: With what I am doing it is more logic to implement it in a module.

Comment: Hmm ... since you put down-vote I wonder if this is possible to rewrite node's template with function. Will keep an eye on this question.

Comment: Yes, it is possible. It's what I am doing at the moment for a couple of nodes, but now I want to do it for "Display Suite", not a node. which doesn't seem to work in the same way

Comment: So you find out how to apply template to a node with function?

Comment: What the function does, is register a certain template which is not in the theme folder (but for example in a module) in the registry. So this has the same effect as putting it in the theme folder.

Comment: So you found an answer to your question? If yes, then publish your answer! At least I would know this method.

Comment: No, this works for "NODES" and "VIEWS" i am trying to do the same for "DISPLAY SUITE" templates